# SOQL on contacts

Tags: apex, soql, size

Hello,

I can't understand why this assertment is true in my DEV450 environment :

```
    // TODO #1: Review the code below to see how we are using  
    //          the assertEquals method of the System class to  
    //          ensure that there are no Contacts in the db.
    // System.debug('Size  : ' + [SELECT LastName FROM Contact].size());
    System.assertEquals(0, [SELECT LastName FROM Contact].size());
```

It seems to be true because the assertion pass,
But I got contacts in my training environment !

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this code is in a test class than it makes sense. At least as long as you do not use the annotation:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
```

In the test classes without this annotation you are just able to access/query the data that you create in your specific test method. The default value for this annotation is false.

Comment: I knew I was missing something enormous !!
Thanks

Comment: Setting the SeeAllData to true is supposed to be an exception for specific test cases (i.e. getting the standard pricebook before the Test.getStandardPricebookId was available).